# How to check screen resolution inside Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, screen-resolution

I tried this code in Fragment to get the window size :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
           .getMetrics(metrics);
```

But it did not return me the actual screen resolution. I want to check the ldpi, hdpi, mdpi screen resolution dynamically inside fragment class. How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int density = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi
```

then you can compare with `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW`, `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM` and the others

```
if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {

} else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Please share some code to check mediam, high density. I am beginner in android.

Comment: Which method is perfect to put this code such as onCreate(), onAttach() or onCreateView().